# Query all RDP sessions using .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, rdp

I am a lot of difficulty finding a way to query all RDP sessions using .net.  Anyone know of a way to return this data without having to parse the results of a qwinsta.exe call?

Currently i am using the qwinsta method, but this is returning some very unexpected results when querying different os installations (2003/2008/2008r2 etc.).

Comment: I suspect there might be a WMI object that has the data you need, but I don't have the first clue what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the various WTS* functions (WTSEnumerateSessions and friends), or using the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/), which provides a wrapper for those unmanaged API calls.